# Updating appWidget gives Problem loading gadget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm trying to add a view to my main RemoteViews but I keep getting Problem loading gadget error. Here's the xmls and code, some help would be appreciated.

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main);
    RemoteViews bookmark = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_items);
    updateViews.addView(R.id.view_container,  bookmark);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);

}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_widget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_4x4_portrait"
>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- New views will be added here at runtime -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the error ? could you put the stack trace please ?

Comment: Widget doesn't show, instead I get Problem loading gadget shown where widget is supposed to be. Nothing shows on Log.e (I didn't test with my own Log because I don't know what to test)

Answer (score 1):

Note also that 2.1 has a bug where

`appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(int ID, RemoteViews rv)`

does not work, you must use

`appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(int [] IDs, RemoteView rv)`.

I simply made a unit length array with my particular `widget ID` as the only element.

Weirdly, both methods work properly in `1.6, 2.0, 2.2 and 2.3`.

Just a pointer for anyone else stuck with non updating `appWidgets`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try : `appWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);` instead `of appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that problem was in addView call, I was adding the new View to itself instead of the main layout on the widget.